# AWS iOS sdk video upload changing conent-type from video/mp4 to video/quicktime

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, content-type

I am uploading a video captured from iphone to aws s3 bucket using S3PutObjectRequest. I am explicitly setting the content-type metadata on the put object request to "video/mp4". Event with that the aws s3 storage shows a content-type "video/quicktime" on upload completion.

I tried the same with aws php sdk with the same file which showed the correct type "video/mp4" that I set. Not sure what's going wrong. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
S3PutObjectRequest *putObjectRequest = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:[videoMetaData generateKey] inBucket: [videoMetaData bucketName ]];
NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoMetaData.videoFilePath];
[putObjectRequest setFilename:videoMetaData.videoFilePath];

putObjectRequest.contentType = @"video/mp4";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your movie file have `.mov` or `.pt` as an extension? Looks like the AWS SDK for iOS automatically overwrites the content type to `video/quicktime` when a file has `.mov` or `.pt` extensions. If you change the extension to `.mp4`, the content type should become `video/mp4`.